# Full scholarship and student advisor relationship

Tags: advisor, funding

If a phd student is completely funded by an outside institution and don't cost the school or the university anything, what impact would that have on the student relationship with his advisor? Especially on things like interest on the student progress.

Comment: Generally agree with @jakebeal's answer, with a couple additional points: 1. I recommend you to edit your question to make it more specific. What aspects of the relationship are of most concern to you. Support and patronage of dissertation work? Attitude toward autonomy (ability to chart your own course through the degree by undertaking independent research)? Being less (or more) constrained by time (depending on duration or strings attached to financial support from the outside institution)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The main effect of external support on a student/advisor relationship is that there is less external pressure for production of short-term results.  Whether this is a good thing or a bad thing depends strongly on the individual student and advisor.

- With less pressure on the student, there is more freedom to develop a unique research agenda but also more opportunity to get "lost" in the possibilities and waste time.
- With less pressure on the advisor, there are fewer boss/employee dynamics in the relationship and generally less strain, but also more opportunity for the advisor to be distracted by other short-term concerns.

A secondary effect is that the student may have less opportunities to be apprenticed in grant-writing, since their support is already assured.

In sum: with a good advisor and a student with a mature outlook, the freedom of external support is a blessing.  If either of those two ingredients is lacking, it can be a problem to lack the forcing functions of external support.

Comment: This makes sense if the alternative is support from the advisor's grant.  But what about the case, common in some fields, where the alternative would be support from the university?  In such cases I don't see why there would be pressure for short-term results.

Comment: @NateEldredge I don't have anything much to say about that case, because I have virtually no experience with it.

Comment: You have missed a strong factor. The funding from external institution  / grants is not eternal. Therefore the student will have to finish before the expiry date of the funding or continue the rest of his PHD probably unfunded.

Comment: @Alexandros, or help the advisor win a follow-on grant.

Comment: @Alexandros Bill's point is what I said about "opportunities to be apprenticed in grant-writing" since in the US, at least, there are few grants that are precisely aligned to a Ph.D.  I recognize that in Europe it more often goes in the other direction, as you say.

Answer (score 1):

First off, having a PhD paid for by an outside institution is a big advantage for any PhD student.  This generally makes it much easier to gain admittance to a PhD program as you are essentially free labor.  **Be sure your advisor can take advantage of this in a way that benefits you.**

I've seen this situation most often when a company foots the bill for an employee.   If this is the case, be sure your advisor's work lines up well with what the company is doing.  You're generally expected to work for the company after graduation, so keep this in mind.

If you are lucky enough to get a full scholarship for the entirety of your PhD, skip to the next paragraph.  If not, keep reading.  Most PhD student "pay" for their education via GRA/GTA positions at the university, and by bringing in outside research grant money.  Many of these grants are called scholarships, and will only last 1 year.

If you are entirely funded from the outside, reach out to people you know who went to the school, and find a prof who has worked with people who are "self-funded".  Some profs are very happy to work within constraints that may be set by your scholarship, while other would prefer you be funded under their projects.

Answer (score 0):

Although each case is unique, my general sense is that advisors tend to care the most about (invest more time/effort into) students who are "their" students, in the sense that they are brought into the program to work with (be funded by) them, to conduct research within their general research field/agenda, and to adhere to their recommendations, including the approximate study plan and time to degree.

With this in mind, the more you can emulate this dynamic (align yourself with advisor in ways that minimize differences caused by independent support), the less awkward the relationship will be.

Answer (score 0):

I am tempted to say that if the student is good, then the professor will push him/her to do more, and vice versa.

A professor's success depends **a lot** on the group's PhD students. Once a hiring decision is made, the professor doesn't really get reminded of who's footing the bill every day. Therefore the level of supervision would stay uniform across the board.

It is very much a semiotic relation, not a parasitic one.